# How to edit the content of a .jar mod (1.8.9)

Tags: java, jar, minecraft, minecraft-forge

The mod creates an InputStream from a URL containing custom chat messages and I'd like to change those messages.
To do so, I'd like to change the URL. How would I be able to do so?

The mod is under 1.8.9

I tried contacting the dev about it but I didn't get any answer. In addition, I decompiled the mod but after importing it into eclipse, I get alot of errors.

Thanks.

Comment: What mod is it? What errors did you get when you decompiled it? Are you willing to disassemble and reassemble the class file instead?

Comment: One other idea: are you willing to make a coremod, to patch the string dynamically at runtime instead of having to edit the other mod's jar at all?

Comment: I get the following error for most of them (there are 2000 errors ): 
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
This could be due to the fact that I used a deobfuscator for forge since it appears forge obfuscates the code when compiling...

Comment: You answered "What errors did you get when you decompiled it?" but not any of my other questions.

Comment: To answer the other questions, yes I am willing to disassemble and reassemble the class file and it is a french mod that helps for a known french server (through custom alerts and other useful things regarding different gamemodes).

Comment: I really like the second idea but I'm not sure I know how to do so.

Comment: I posted an answer, but it's really vague. I can make it more specific, but you'd need to tell me exactly what mod you're talking about and give me a link to it so I can download the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Find the class file that contains the URL you want to change, then choose an option for how to change it.

## Option 1: editing the jar

Extract the class file, and run a Java disassembler such as [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) on it (note: not `javap`, since you can't reassemble its output). Change the URL in the disassembly, then reassemble it (Krakatau can do this too). In the jar file, replace the class file you disassembled with the one you reassembled. (Remember, jar files are just renamed zip files.) Check the META-INF folder to make sure there isn't a signature/checksum that you invalidated.

## Option 2: reflection

Even if a field is private, you can access it with reflection. Create a regular mod of your own that uses reflection to get the URL and change it. Note that this method won't work if the URL is hardcoded into the function or if it's `static final`.

## Option 3: coremod

Coremods are a feature supported by Minecraft Forge to let you use [ObjectWeb ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) to manipulate classes as they're being loaded. Create a coremod of your own. It should have a loading plugin and a class transformer. The loading plugin should set up the class transformer in the path of all loaded classes. The class transformer should use a ClassReader to read the class, then make the necessary change, then a ClassWriter to write it back out.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a alot for your answer! I'll keep you updated on my findings!

Comment: Ok so I followed your first option and everything is fine, the mod loads fine but it appears it caused a critical error which results in my game crashing upon loading.
the game output states that: "Critical problem: mixins.espritderuche.json:EntityMixin target net.minecraft.entity.Entity was already transformed."

Comment: @BichBich Without the error, I have no way of knowing what's wrong, and without a name and link to the mod, there's a good chance I still won't.

Comment: @BichBich 1. Can you get a crash report with only the mod you're editing, instead of a bunch of mods? 2. Can you please post the name of the mod in question?

Comment: Well when it is the only mod, it is working. So first of all I'd like to thank you for your help :)
The name of the mod is EspritDeRuche but I don't think you'll find it as it is a private mod. I will now look into potential cross-mod issues. Thanks again!